# Не отображаются картинки на сайте

Tags: php

Есть сайт, который при запросе к папке с картинкой, делает редирект(через htacces) на контроллер который делает ресайз под нужный размер, если его нету в кеше сервера. Так вот, проблема в том, что при загрузке страницы, картинки не отображаются, при этом в папке с нужным размером они создаются, но при переходе из браузера отображается маленький черный квадрат. На локальном сервере такой проблемы нет, только на reg.ru В чем может быть проблема? php 5.6

Comment: Супер секретный код в студию), Так же узнайте версию пыхи на хосте и настройки сервака.

Comment: Мне нужна лишь подсказка в чем может быть дело. Что на локальном сервере картинка ресайзится и к ней можно получить доступ по ссылке, а на сервере она создается но при первом открытии там пусто(хотя в каталоге есть) Файлы локалки и сервера одинаковые вместе с htaccess

Comment: путь до картинки неправильный?

Comment: Путь правильный. И если перейти по нему и обновить страницу еще раз то картинка отображается, хотя и при первом переходе она уже есть в каталоге.